# Punteros a funciones y parámetros indeterminados en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void saludo();
void despedida();

int main(){
    void (*Ptr_Funciones[2])() = {saludo, despedida};
    (Ptr_Funciones[0])();
    (Ptr_Funciones[1])();

    return 0;
}

void saludo(){
    cout<<"\nHola mundo";
}

void despedida(){
    cout<<"\nAdios mundo"<<endl<<endl;
}
```

En base a esto, se me generaron unas cuantas preguntas las cuales investigue antes de preguntar pero no entendí del todo.

Las preguntas son:

1. ¿Como hago un array de funciones, si estas son de distinto tipo?
2. Se que en C++ se usa esta notación para los parámetros indeterminados: (type var ...)
   La cosa es que no se como interactuar con estos dentro de la función.
3. De ser la pregunta 1 y 2 posible, ¿Se pueden combinar dichos puntos al momento de crear arrays de funciones?

De verdad que he investigado. Pero no encuentro mucha información, y la poca que encontré no la entendí muy bien. Espero que me puedan colaborar.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Como hago un array de funciones, si estas son de distinto tipo?

No lo haces. C++ no permite formaciones<sup>1</sup> de tipos heterogéneos. Si tienes una formación tiene que ser del mismo tipo.

Pero puedes encerrar el puntero a función en un objeto que derive de un único objeto que será el tipo de la formación:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };

template <typename retorno_t, typename ... pack_parametros>
struct Funcion : public Base
{
    using funcion_t = retorno_t(pack_parametros ...);

    Funcion(funcion_t f) : funcion{f} {}
    funcion_t *funcion;
};
```

Esto te permitirá hacer una formación de funciones:

```
using puntero = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

short f1();
int f2(int a);
long f3(int a, int b);
float f4(int a, int b, int c);
double f5(int a, int b, int c, int d);

template <typename retorno_t, typename ... pack_parametros>
auto funcion(retorno_t(f)(pack_parametros ...))
{
    return puntero{new Funcion<retorno_t, pack_parametros ...>{f}};
}

int main()
{
    puntero funciones[5]{funcion(f1), funcion(f2), funcion(f3), funcion(f4), funcion(f5)};
    return 0;
}
```

Aunque no es del todo útil, ya que para poder llamarlas [tienes que conocer su tipo](https://tio.run/##pZTPb9owFMfP@K94oofGbUAlwAXSHDat0i4dmthhWqvIOA6LlthZYm@qIvanj9n5QSgzm7r54jyb9/m@Z38NzfMRTQnf7vcXCaepihj4iShlwUgWoH4tY5kongKE9JaiEl6RkkEF35JCKpLCDxM7GG4hYjFRqVzCbomQZFmeEqnz5VPOOMkYFEyKgotQunBYG4/HkBP6JcxJoWNZiDLohO4Up4ngsIBcbdKE1sqoQgNVJnwLcbMdSi19QDsnMCOAdTmDFub0WTHW5Das4h1UOzTod6/azyUy3TSKueKSFULrlTJaLBRPvioW5rLwTWXBf3ZNlBRdPU7fUIytPWFzEPpXquBdXRVn37tD849kLemBblj3tUPoQt9awhmsmp6oUBJ8H8Jw9f7Nev0xvPtw/3r99t19GJrlywd@qY3wWRT6/Cb61v80KlgtoS1xol2BEq6zPMdMBP8l71k1w0CPofkidejr8cCHB7pn6Kkwppg2eBfMtMH/QN9YJaZGIk4F0S3Mnmk0E8UvlaBWnfEsNkqR0JZnEM9tUs0U4RcpRXa5uVGrbyYjCXdqW3U@b83Iyk/zx6pzZjzB7sGmsXccTI@D2XEwx@YVDUpJZEJDSkrpd0atzRTAVeD0cjeP4y2TDsajoEPoR2xN15XXx3FCmPxOmJxDGOPUDBvIs4Bc8M6xaof0MBtxaie6MD0HbcxwQrWhZ2fRLszqv8H22m/029/vf9I4JdtyP9IOuqXX1x75BQ):

```
static_cast<Funcion<short> *>(funciones[0].get())->funcion();
static_cast<Funcion<int, int> *>(funciones[1].get())->funcion(1);
static_cast<Funcion<long, int, int> *>(funciones[2].get())->funcion(1, 2);
static_cast<Funcion<float, int, int, int> *>(funciones[3].get())->funcion(1, 2, 3);
static_cast<Funcion<double, int, int, int, int> *>(funciones[4].get())->funcion(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.